# Can you see the values of NSUserDefaults anywhere in the xcode debugger?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, nsuserdefaults

Can you see the values of NSUserDefaults naywhere in the xcode debugger?

Just wondering if this is possible?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Hey sorry @David, doing it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't have a solution to view them in the debugger, but I can offer this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@", [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

For some caveman-debugging:)

EDIT: As David suggest in the comment, we can now do this in the debugging console:

```
po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]
```

Swift 3.0

```
po UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  
  
Just do this in the debugger:  
`po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]`

Answer (score 10):

I haven't done it but you should be able to execute a po (print object) command on the user defaults like so:

```
po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"someKeyName"]
```

I prefer to wrap my defaults in a custom class and create a description method that dumps the defaults.

You can use the "defaults" command line utility to examine the defaults exactly. Read the man page for details.

Answer (score 4):

Not aware of any GUI that displays NSUserDefaults, but I use this in my application delegate to see the settings at start up:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"%@ DEFAULTS = %@", [self class], [defaults persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can log or either use PO command at debugger 
for Keys :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);
```

or for Keys and values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

& on debugger use:
getting all keys :

```
 po [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]
```

for key & values :

```
po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated for Swift 5

Print all UserDefault **key-value pairs** to console:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

---

Print UserDefault **keys** to console:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)
```

---

Print UserDefault **values** to console:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values)
```

Answer (score 0):

read:

```
po UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "key")
```

write:

```
po UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "key")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add an expression directly on **the Variable breakpoint view** and adding : `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()` see the image below .

[add breakpoint view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ava95.png)